# Change owner in for all folders within and below working directory but not the working folder itself

Tags: bash, find, chown

I like to change the owner of all folders within and below the current working folder, but not the working folder itself.

I tried:

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod name:group
```

This works OK, but it also changes the owner of the current working folder which is ./

How can I avoid to change the owner of the current working folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-mindepth` primitive to apply it only to directories at least 1 level below .:

```
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod name:group
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Davisson got me on the right path. Thanks for that.

just 2 things:

'-mindepth' must be before '-type' otherwise find complaints
and
--mindepth' must be set to 2 (as one seems to be the current folder.

So:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod name:group
```

works perfect.

Thanks